# How to disable the send mail for importing data

Tags: email, email-template, massemailmessage

I'm newbie was salesforce and i create the Email alert with the condition is working fine.But it was sending mass mail when i import data by data loader. In my salesforce we use the dataloader to create the account/contact. I don't want to send the mail to contact created by dataloader.
I want to send mail directly created by using salesforce crm.

Please suggest me a way to send the email to the account created by salesforce crm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to disable send email but you can go for any alternative solution.

1. Create a custom field (checkbox) on Account object called ImportException__c and mark that true while importing through data loader and include that field in your email alert workflow by indicating __c =TRUE, This is not a cure-all obviously.
2. Create a custom setting into your org and create same checkbox custom field. Make that TRUE prior your import operation

you need to add following condition into your email alert

```
$Setup.BypassRules__c.Disable_Emamil_alert__c
```

Here BypassRule__c is custom setting name and Disable_Email_Alert is checkbox field name.

3. You can deactivate Email Deliverability Setup->Email Administration->Deliverability -> No Access prior to import

Comment: In 3rd step not suitable for me. sometime user also use the dataloader. In the workflow what is the indicating_c???

Comment: i add the importexpection field in my workflow. But i don't  know how to add the $Setup.BypassRules__c.Disable_Emamil_alert__c and where i want to add

Comment: I add the condition workflow using if condition but it does not sending the mail created by salesforce.

Comment: You need to make that custome setting true while uploading after uploading make that false again

Comment: How to send mail created by salesforce otherwise no. Because my user also using salesforce as well as dataloader.

Comment: If you have that case then please go with option #1

Comment: I have one doubt. I create the custom import checkbox. How to make it checked when i uploaded by dataloader automatically....

Comment: is it custom field on Account object right? if yes then add new column with that field and add value as true

Comment: yes, i create the custom field and how to add new column in that page

Comment: There is no need to add that on page layout. you will add that field as column in csv only, will mark as true.

Comment: oh ok.... When i uploaded file by i need to add the custom field and make as true... And one doubt i need to make as mandatory field because my user also use

Comment: that is not required I guess, you can define a template and communicate with your users for this change.

Comment: ok thank you so much once test with my org and if i face any pbm i getback to u

Comment: If( AND(ISPICKVAL( Stage__c , "Login"),(ImportException__c = TRUE)),
 $Setup.BypassRule_c__c.Disable_Email_Alert__c,
null
).      This is my condition but now is not sending mail directly created also

Comment: Now how to enable sending mail to directly created data

Comment: If you are using custom field from account object to manage this. Remove $setup condition

Comment: on the above condition If( AND(ISPICKVAL( Stage__c , "Login"),(ImportException__c = TRUE)),
 $Setup.BypassRule_c__c.Disable_Email_Alert__c,
AND(ISPICKVAL( Stage__c , "Login"),(ImportException__c = TRUE)),
) it is correct????

Comment: use following condition.  If( AND(ISPICKVAL( Stage__c , "Login"),(ImportException__c = FALSE)),true,false)

it will send email if user is creating from frontend otherwise it will avoid email alert. make sure default is set to false for ImportException__c

Comment: yes once i upload by dataloader that time i add the custom field column name.It's enough???

Comment: yes add the column name and value as true